# Mac terminal auto-complete is suggesting files not in current directory

Tags: macos, terminal, autocomplete

No matter where the termial promt is in the filesystem, it suggests only executables from bin or sbin dir.

Take a look at this:

```
Last login: Sun Apr 26 15:24:57 on ttys004
You have mail.
box:~ mee$ A
AppleFileServer           AssetCacheLocatorUtil     AssetCacheManagerUtil     AssetCacheTetheratorUtil  
box:~ mee$ which AppleFileServer 
/usr/sbin/AppleFileServer
box:~ mee$ 
Display all 2636 possibilities? (y or n)
box:~ mee$ cd ~/Desktop/wp-content/
box:wp-content mee$ ls
index.php   languages   plugins     themes      upgrade     uploads
box:wp-content mee$ 
Display all 2636 possibilities? (y or n)
box:wp-content mee$ A
AppleFileServer           AssetCacheLocatorUtil     AssetCacheManagerUtil     AssetCacheTetheratorUtil
```

Edit: I have created a new admin user to see if the problem persists, but the same error is there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's as expected if you're completing the executable; completion follows the path. If you want completion in the local directory, you're likely going to have to type `./` before you hit the completion key, since frequently `.` is excluded from the path variable.

In this case, the completion is "smart" in that it is taking what it believes to be the context and using that to determine what you want. In this case, at the beginning of the line, it thinks you want to complete a command that can actually be executed, and thus it will only find things in the path.